# How can I solve a divergent integral with Mathematica?

Tags: integration

I would like to ask you something about an integral on Mathematica.
My function is
$$
  \Phi (\alpha, \tau) = \int^0_{-\infty} dk_{\alpha} A(k_{\alpha}) e^{ik_{\alpha}\alpha} (\frac{1}{2ik_{\alpha}}) \tau^{2ik_{\alpha}}
$$
where $A(k_{\alpha}) = e^{-k_{\alpha}^2}$, $\alpha$ and $\tau$ assumed values.

It diverges in 0 so I used a numerical integration with a number near 0. Then I have to do the derivative of this function but I'm wondering about how to do it.

Any help? I would like also to know if there are methods to integrate $\Phi$ in analytical way.

Comment: Hi Laria, your question could use some clarification. Since the integral is divergent, it has no intrinsic finite value. What principle do you have in mind to regularize it to obtain a unique finite value (this is independent of the software you want to use to compute it)? Perhaps you've noticed that your integrand depends on $\alpha$ and $\tau$ only via the combination $\alpha+2\log\tau$. What variable, or combination of variables do you want to differentiate with?

Comment: Note that there is a Stack Exchange site specifically dedicated to Mathematica at https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I solved it, many thanks anyway